# Eclipse stops working, hangs and stops responding to any actions

Tags: java, eclipse, freeze, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse hangs.
I've run jstack on the process and got the following:

```
 "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f531000b000 nid=0xbd3 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f5317b69000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.jna.SVNGnomeKeyring$3.callback(SVNGnomeKeyring.java:88)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000606027b40> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:455)
    at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2302)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3361)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Eclipse version is:

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
```

Plugins:

```
Subclipse 1.10.5 with:
  Subclipse (Required)  1.10.5  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group   tigris.org
  Subversion Client Adapter (Required)  1.10.1  org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group   tigris.org
  SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required)  1.8.9   org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group    tigris.org
  SVNKit Library    1.7.9.r9659_v20130411_2103  org.tmatesoft.svnkit.feature.group  TMate Software
```

OS:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Any ideas how to resove it? I tried to reinstall plugins, reinstall Eclipse itself. The problem still exists.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to fetch credentials for your SVN from keyring... I didn't know GNOME had keyring. Maybe it's showing you log-in dialog somewhere? Eclipse has problems sometimes with bringing things to front so maybe the keyring prompt is just hidden by Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Issue 1651](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1651) in the Subclipse issue tracker, which falls right between Subclipse, SVNKit and GNOME Keyring.

The issue can be worked around by configuring Subversion *not* to use GNOME Keyring. If storing credentials in plaintext is acceptable, Subversion may be configured as following:

1. In `~/.subversion/servers`, under `[global]`, set `store-passwords` and `store-plaintext-passwords` to `yes`:

   ```
   [global]
   #...skipping...
   #
   # Password / passphrase caching parameters:
   store-passwords = yes
   store-plaintext-passwords = yes
   ```
2. In `~/.subversion/config`, under `[auth]`, set `password-stores` to an empty string:

   ```
   [auth]
   #...skipping...
   ### To disable all password stores, use an empty list:
   password-stores =
   ```

   (Tested on Subversion 1.9.5, configuration may differ for other versions.)